# Is CSS @import causing omission of file extension?

Tags: html, css, import

I'm integrating a header from one website to another.
the header relies on external css files, as well as on js files.

I've tried an approach of using the `<style scoped>` with `@import url('')` inside it
to constrain the effects of the imported css (using frames is not an option...)

The issue is that this lines of code:

```
<style scoped>
@import url("https://staging.redmatch.com/Staging_RecruiterPro/Candidate/FileServer/Affiliates/512888/CSS/system.base.css?n7xfen");
</style>
```

creates the following request (as seen using fiddler):

```
https://staging.redmatch.com/Staging_RecruiterPro/Candidate/FileServer/Affiliates/512888/CSS/system.base?n7xfen
```

So my question is,
Why is the **.css** ommited and can this issue be resolved?

regards,
jerom

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Browser_compatibility), we should consider following things to let  **scoped** feature work:

> `[1] Supported in Chrome 20+ by enabling the "Enable <style scoped>" or "experimental WebKit features" flag in chrome://flags.`
>
> `[2] Gecko 20 and later implement :scope pseudo-classes, but the preference layout.css.scope-pseudo.enabled must be set to true. This is only the case by default in Nightly and Aurora test versions.`

..and also check the [live example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Live_sample) in the same link to know whether your browser supports `scope` attribute or not.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out. I was under the impression 'scoped' was much more browser supported.

Comment: @yaronhochman you are welcome. Please mark this post as accepted answer if this post solved your problem. :)